# Accessing Firefox's clipboard in windows

Tags: python, firefox, clipboard, pywin32

I have a Python program that uses win32clipboard to place a string on the clipboard:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('test', 13)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

This works perfectly fine, except in Firefox. If I ctrl-c something in FF (let's say 'SO', then let my program do its thing, and then press ctrl-v, 'SO' is pasted, instead of 'test'. Can I somehow alter this behaviour of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This should alter the behavior in Firefox, since you need to EmptyClipboard() first.

```
clipboard = 'Test'
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText( clipboard, 13 )
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does empty the clipboard, but after that, SetClipboardText() still doesn't work.